# PHP picking time intervals from database?

Tags: php, sql, date

I have a database with a column full of timestamps, I've got it returning all the values in php while converting them to normal time format (12:00:01) using the code below but seeing as I want to put them onto a graph I need a way of seriously limiting them down (currently 23,922 rows). I was thinking of using the values in 10-15 minute intervals but can't find a way of doing it. Anyone have any recommendations? Cheers, John.

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) 
{ 
   echo date("H:i:s", $info['timestamp']);
}
```

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: It would make it easier to provide an answer if we knew more about what you're trying to do. Do you want to group together results and provide an average? Do you want to show all data points in a 10-15 minute range? What specific outcome are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What does your SQL query look like? What is stopping you from throwing in a `WHERE timest ...`?

Comment: Aggregating data with PHP is like using a spoon to dig a hole. It's the wrong tool for the job. Do this with SQL.

Comment: We have little time to finish a small university project and as we all know mysql we've chosen to use that as it wont be gone before the project is marked, and we've been told we'd gain nothing from using PDO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "timestamps" are actual timestamps (column type timestamp) you can use simple > or < operators to filter the results, like: where timestamp > "2013-02-20 16:10:00"

If they are integers or strings you can use FROM_UNIXTIME() or other function that may match your data (assuming your DB is MySQL see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Even when data is saved as varchar MySQL DB are smart enough for some math, it is not as efficient as saving them with a proper type but it can work:

```
SELECT `timestamp`
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE `timestamp` >= ( 
    SELECT MAX( `timestamp` ) max
      FROM  yourtable
  ) - ( 60 *15 ) -- 15 minutes
```

Comment: No they're VARCHAR :/ unfortunately as this is a project I have no control over the data I've been given. I think I may have worded this a bit badly. I want to just limit the output to make sure there's at least 15 minutes between each one  I.e say I had the following:
12:00:00,
12:01:15,
12:01:20,
12:05:18,
12:07:45,
12:10:00,
12:11:32

The only output I would get would be :
12:00:00,
12:05:18,
12:10:00

and the others would be missed out?

Comment: But is the 15 minutes a necessary limit or do you just want to limit the results? You can easily limit the number of results you get from the DB using something like "LIMIT 0, 10" to get the first 10 results

Comment: Assuming it is a MySQL DB and the timestamps are unix timestamps (seconds since the epoch, 1/1/1970) you can use something like "WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)"

Comment: It is a MySQL database and they are unix timestamps but running that code doesn't return any values from the database?

Comment: Tested "DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)" and returns a proper date time, 15 minutes before current time. Tested "FROM_UNIXTIME( 1290000000 )" and got 2010-11-17 13:20:00, so there's no reason why it wouldn't work, could u pastebin.com me your latest timestamps?

Comment: It's a database of tweets so they're all oldish time stamps. I'm not sure why today's date needs to come into it? I just need to limit them down so thought I'd only select the ones at 15 minute intervals as at the moment there's one for every few seconds.

Comment: Oh sorry, you need an interval, instead of NOW() you will have to find the newest, added a query that should work for you to the answer

Comment: thanks I understand up to the point of  - ( 60 *15 ), it runs the query fine but it only gives back one answer?